# Can I put Shift Keys back in machine?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

So I redeemed Some shift keys in the pre-sequel and I took them out using one of my characters, but I haven't used them. Is there a way to put them back and use them with with another character or will all my keys be gone if I use another character?

Answer (score 4):

You don't actually have to do anything, all of your golden keys are automatically shared between all of your characters.